# Python elif statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I don't understand why my following piece of code does not work:

```
running = True
name = input("Whats your name?: ")
print ("Hi", name, "Which Program Would You Like to Use")
print ("1. Upper to Lower Case converter")
print ("2. Lower to Upper Case converter")
print ("3. Character Count")

x = input("Enter the Number: ")

if  x==1:
    print ("You have selected the Upper to Lower Case converter")
    y = input("Enter the text you would like converted: ")
    print (y.lower())
elif x==2:
    pass print ("You have selected the Lower to Upper Case converter")
    z = input("Enter the text you would like converted: ")
    print (z.lower()

running = False
```

Comment: I guess you have a while loop somewhere for that? also indentation is wrong. Maybe thats why it does not work.

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? What steps have you tried? What's the intended result? You need to provide more information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Shall I assume its not an indentation problem?

Answer (score 3):

you need here:

```
x = int(input("Enter the Number: "))
```

input takes as string

```
if x==1:   you were comparing string with integer
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably are missing a closing bracket here: `print (z.lower()`

In this statement `if  x==1:`, you are comparing `x`, which is a string, with an `int`, and, as you already might have understood, you cannot do it.

One solution for this problem is to convert `x` to and `int` directly when you get the input from the user:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Or comparing the `x` with a string number:

```
if x== "1":
    # do stuff
```

It depends of course in what you want to do.

Comment: Hi! so I converted x to int. But I am still getting an error saying "Invalid Syntax" on else and elif statements when I try to run the module. I haven't finished writing the program though.